# Do I need to add a privacy "purpose string" to my app's Info.plist to allow it to run on iOS 10?

Tags: ios, ios10, privacy, info.plist

### General Query

Does precise documentation exist for which API methods/properties require privacy "purpose strings" in iOS 10?

### Specific Query

I have an app that links against the `CoreBluetooth` framework that accesses only the following methods/properties:

#### CBCentralManager:

- `state`
- `- retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:`

#### CBPeripheral:

- `name`

In the documentation, I have found the following vague statements (emphases mine):

> An iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0 must include in its Info.plist file the usage description keys for the types of data it needs to access or it will crash. **To access Bluetooth peripheral data specifically**, it must include NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription.
>
> [...]
>
> When the system prompts the user to allow usage, the value that you provide for this key is displayed as part of the alert.
>
> [...]
>
> To protect user privacy, an iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0, **and which accesses the Bluetooth interface**, must statically declare the intent to do so. Include the NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key in your app’s Info.plist file and provide a purpose string for this key. **If your app attempts to access the Bluetooth interface without a corresponding purpose string, your app exits**.
>
> [...]
>
> The data and features that require user permission are described in [Table 1-2](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ExpectedAppBehaviors/ExpectedAppBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW7).

(Table 1.2 states that `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` is required to access "**Bluetooth peripherals**")

My app does *not* currently exit when it calls the APIs listed. Neither does it "prompt the user to allow usage".

However, [this blog post](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/privacy-settings-in-ios-10/) suggests that the lack of a crash does *not* indicate that no purpose string is required.

(Despite the fact that my app is not "linked on or after iOS 10.0" (the current version has been in the store since before iOS 10 existed), it *does* crash citing a missing `NSCameraUsageDescription` when it attempts to access the camera.)

Furthermore, my reading of the documentation above suggests that I *should* be including an entry for `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription`.

Is there any other documentation that I've missed that lists which actual API calls are covered by which privacy purpose strings?

Do I need to add an entry for `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` to my `Info.plist`?

Is there any harm in adding such an entry if it turns out not to be required?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're definitely need it, it was optional in pre-ios10 but now you have to explicit add the comment into the info.plist 
**IF you're build with iOS10**. It will crash the app but If you build with pre-ios 10 it's fine. It's based on Xcode build not based on Device version

So basically, next time you update the app you need to add it.

and By the way, I couldn't find document for it, this is my own experience that we have when shifting from iOS9 to iOS10

Comment: The question isn't about whether "purpose strings" are ever required. The documentation I quoted clearly states that they are. The question is about whether or not I am using the specific functionality *for which* they are required.

Comment: Sorry Misunderstand it. But If u used Bluetooth, you have to declare it. We Working on the app that use Beacon and we have to explicit declare it here.